# How to filter a dimension hierarchy based on another dimension hierarchy in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a sender and recipient dimensions which are role playing dimensions out of employee physical table.
My fact table has sender, recipient ,messages columns.
I want to get messages sent from a employee to everyone in the company except those reporting to his manager.
I tried something like this

```
WITH 
  SET [Others] AS 
    Except
    (
      Ascendants([Recipient].[Manager])
     ,[Sender].[Manager].Parent
    ) 
SELECT 
  [OTHERS] ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Measures].[Messages]} ON ROWS
FROM [cube]
WHERE 
  [Sender].[Manager].&[xyz];
```

Basic idea is..get all ascendants of the recipients of a given sender and filter those whose ascendant list consists of senders parent.

This doesn't work because I can't do except between two different dimension hierarchies.

Comment: ok - as you say in this scenario `Except` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the `Set` more context aware via the keyword `EXSITING` and then use Filter to compare `member_caption`

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SenderName] AS 
    [Sender].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  SET [ExistingRecip] AS 
    (EXISTING 
      [Recipient].[Manager].MEMBERS) 
  SET [Others] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [ExistingRecip]
     ,
        [ExistingRecip].Item(
        [ExistingRecip].CurrentOrdinal - 1).Member_Caption
      <> 
        [Measures].[SenderName]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [OTHERS] ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Measures].[Messages]} ON ROWS
FROM [cube]
WHERE 
  [Sender].[Manager].&[xyz];
```

Comment: It works but super slow performance on a 100K employee table and 26M fact table

Comment: `Filter` is a slow function - I think it is iterative and the `mdx` calculation engine does not work in `block mode`. I'll try to think of a different approach.